# Multiple textBox validation and their combinations

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, textbox

I have multiple textBoxes in my WPF and want to check whether they are filled out right according to the required application logic:
textBox1 - always mandadory to fill out  
textBox2 - always mandadory to fill out 
 

textBox3 - if !string.IsNullOrEmpty -> textBox4 MUST be filled out too

textBox4 - if !string.IsNullOrEmpty -> textBox3 MUST be filled out too

textBox5 - if !string.IsNullOrEmpty -> textBox6 MUST be filled out too

textBox6 - if !string.IsNullOrEmpty -> textBox5 MUST be filled out too

So either texBox3 and 4 are filled out -OR- textBox5 and 6 or all of them 3 + 4 + 5 +6.
I have tried with if statements, if statements with || boolean logic and so on. I always get stuck ending up with a non-working solution.
This is a straight forward start though, but never got further with something that would work:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))                    
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Fill out textBox1 and textBox2");                
  }
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))                    
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Fill out textBox1 and textBox2"); 
     return;               
  }
// two filled out or two empty
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text) != string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text)) 
{
     MessageBox.Show("Fill out or empty textBox3 and textBox4");
     return;                
}
// two filled out or two empty
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox5.Text) != string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox6.Text)) 
{
     MessageBox.Show("Fill out or empty textBox5 and textBox6"); 
     return;               
}
// if all empty error
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox5.Text)) 
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Fill out 3,4 or 5,6 or 3,4,5,6");                
    }
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much :)